# Is there a public delegate called when GUI of Game view window is updated (Unity Editor)?

Tags: c#, unity-editor

Here is the way to access GUI delegate of Scene view window and draw custom tools/features with it:

```
UnityEditor.SceneView.onSceneGUIDelegate += MyToolFunction;
```

Can I access similar delegate but within Game view window?